# is there any limit to create ingress gateways

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

recently I'm trying to create ingress gateways per API I create, I need to know that is there any limit for that, or can we create as many as I want?

Comment: add the yaml please

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer depends on which Ingress Controller you are using, but if there are limits for any of them, expect them to be in the billions (like the kind of limit where 2^32 or 2^64 are involved because there's an integer index on something somewhere).

Comment: I'm using Nginx ingress controller

Comment: What you would have to check is both the max number of vhosts and nginx proxy rules but I’m sure both are comfortably in the billions. Etcd will be a melted pile of slag with all the api calls before nginx breaks a sweat.